# Story in which space-exploring humans land on planet inhabited by gentle furry creatures who end up committing racial suicide

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Looking for title, author, and original science fiction magazine in which published--probably in 1950's--likely Analog, Astounding, or Galaxy.

Story synopsis: Human explorers in spaceship encounter and land on planet inhabited by gentle furry creatures that resemble Teddy bears.

The encounter is friendly, with humans and alien creatures spending long nights in discussion around campfire, getting to know each other.

The aliens all end up committing racial suicide rather than compete or war with the humans.

Comment: Part of your description reminds me of Robert Sheckley's "Warrior Race" (which you can read at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29548) but I'm pretty sure that's not the one you're looking for.

Comment: Can you provide more details? What causes the conflict between the human explorers and the "friendly" natives? Do the humans want to colonize, or hunt, or extract resources, or enslave them, or what? How do they commit suicide: knives, swords, pistols, poison, drowning?

Comment: Sounds a bit like "Decision at Doona", by Anne McCaffrey, except the race that committed suicide is not the same race being encountered in the book - though they are often brought up.  Your short story might be backstory, or inspiration, or entirely unrelated, I just thought of it when reading your description.

Comment: This sort of reminds me of the Little Fuzzy series by H. Beam Piper, but I'm not 100% sure as I'm not sure that species killed themselves off.

Comment: One might argue that in Poul Anderson and Gordon Dickson Hoka stories that the teddy bearish Hoka commit cultural suicide by abandoning their native culture for the more attractive cultures they find described in human literature,

Comment: @user14111 New to this site, I don't know if I am responding to your question in the proper location, via correct device, etc. That said, I read the story nearly sixty years ago--I'm seeking identification in order to reread and recapture the very details you ask. Always enamored with the outdoors, the scenes of humans and aliens sharing long nights of discussions around campfire stuck with me most; thought it might trigger someone's memory. Have vague notion aliens might have telepathically "looked into humans' souls." All died overnight, though, perhaps save one left alive to explain.

Comment: @user14111 "Warrior Race"  is not it; I skimmed it in link you provided. The aliens MIGHT HAVE simply willed themselves dead, but I don't want to misdirect. I think the gist of the tale was that the aliens loved the humans, but either saw the dark side of their souls or (telepathically or otherwise) discovered their history (perhaps through the shared campfire tales) and did not want to go down the path of conflict. Humans are left with the planet, but also overwhelming guilt and sense of loss.

Comment: @ mwarren and infixed  I'm pretty sure it was a stand-alone short story, not part of a series. Illustrations of Hoka in early edition of "Earthman's Burden" do seem familiar; but then there are only so many ways one can portray "teddy bearish" creatures.

Answer (score 5):

"[What Now, Little Man?](https://sfshortstories.com/?p=765)" by Mark Clifton matches a lot of the features. Human travellers, bearlike and kind aliens, night bonfires. But the relationship is not that kind - humans are made sterile by the voyage, and they basically enslave the kind aliens.

Available to read on archive.org [here](https://archive.org/details/MerrilEdTheYearsBestSF05/Merril_ed%20-%20The%20Year%27s%20Best%20SF%2005/page/n275/mode/2up).

Comment: Good, I guess. Seeing as the **main** point seems to be the racial suicide, I wish you would have **told** us whether that point matches or not. Now I will have to go and find my copy and read the story before I can upvote your answer.

Comment: The main point is not made clear by the author. There is no extinction in the story, but the goonies do not defend themselves against slavery and slaughter ('the only edible animal on the planet is the goonie'), but they prosper rather than die. Humans do not die but can't reproduce either - although the ones on Earth are alive and well. It /could/ be interpreted as suicide risk for either race, but it's ambiguous, hence the title.

Comment: It's a good story, and maybe it's the one the OP remembers. From my hasty reading, though, it seems that the humans and aliens do not have long discussions, getting to know each other.

Comment: True. There's a bonfire, but it's part of a torture setup. But there's also a spot for humans to contemplate the stars and try and figure out themselves. I figure it's possible to mix up the two, although I found it a very poignant story - one that's not easily confused with a story of companionship.