# Story about sentient beings on a planet rapidly evolving because of rapid climate change from glacial conditions to warming then back to glacial

Tags: story-identification

Researchers on this plant were studying the most intelligent animal on the planet. I think they had a binary star system that caused climate conditions to vacillate between very hot and very cold conditions.

The creatures were intelligent enough to be used for domestic chores such as housekeeping. The extreme climatic challenges were causing them to become more intelligent at a very rapid pace.

Comment: Hi there. That's useful info already, but please [edit] in some more details: when did you read that? (It's a written work right? Short story, novel, book series?) As well as any other recollection that [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) could remind you of. Cheers!

Comment: Might this be ["The Brotherhood of Keepers"](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_British_Ed._v16n09_1960-11/page/n55) by Dean McLaughlin, as previously answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212013/101407)?

Comment: That is it David. The title rang a bell and the first few lines cinched it. I'm so pleased to have discovered this website. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: @DavidW put that as a proper answer here, for this question to be properly answered and so that we'll have a master thread to point to :) Geoff, once David will have written his answer, you'll be able to accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left. Welcome to the site, don't hesitate to ask more, or provide answers! :)

Comment: I recall a story where humans landed (crashed?) on a planet with either a highly elliptical orbit or in a binary star system with other star approaching. The planet is going to get VERY hot soon. To make a long story short, they learn that the whole planets ecosystem will change, new species being born from the existing plants and animals/creatures and when the sun recedes they will die and the original species will be reborn. Some of the original species will seal themselves in Ice caves to live until the sun recedes to educate the next generation.

Comment: Pretty sure the cover of the paperback book I described had a human (wearing a t-shirt and backpack) and an alien standing on a tall rock in a desert type environment looking around. (If I recall right the two of them got stranded there and were hiking back to civilization)

Answer (score 9):

I think this is ["The Brotherhood of Keepers"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55582) by Dean McLaughlin.  The planet has a strange orbit that takes it between 2 stars in a binary system, which causes it to have episodic global hot and cold periods.  The Earth research station has been there for a thousand years, observing, and the researchers have noted that the natives ("floppers") have been becoming increasingly intelligent.  The first natives contacted, who are helping at the station, have not gotten more intelligent because of a lack of evolutionary pressure, but some of the wild floppers that are being captured further away are becoming as smart as humans or maybe even smarter.

You can read the story from [scans on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_British_Ed._v16n09_1960-11/page/n55).  There are more details at [this previous answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/212013/101407).

Comment: I remember reading this many years ago and might have asked a question about it  myself soon or later.  So the star system is Xi Scorpii.